# Load local resources with NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I'm using NLTK with python 3.  I'd like to load a custom pickle from a file knowing the file name.

I currently have the pickle in a directory like:

```
/path/to/project/nltk/tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle
```

I would like to load this and use it like so:

```
import nltk
sent_tokenizer = nltk.data.load('file:/path/to/project/nltk/tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
tokens = sent_tokenizer('A really big hunk of text.')
```

However, it seems that NLTK infers that I don't already have a python 3 version of the resource and adds in `PY3` to my desired path:

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource '/path/to/project/nltk/tokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle
  ' not found.  Please use the NLTK Downloader to
  obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - ''
**********************************************************************
```

I would like to be able to use the real path to the file, instead of leaving out the `PY3` folder and expecting NLTK to insert it.  Is there a way to directly import the resource without NLTK modifying the path?

Thanks!
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they're your resources, load them without going through the nltk's `data.load` API. Pickled resources can simply be unpickled:

```
with open("/path/to/english.pickle", "rb") as resource:
    sent_tokenizer = pickle.load(resource)
```